# Joomla 1.6 - what does this error mean? Call to a member function save() on a non-object in

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla

Call to a member function save() on a non-object in .../views/manufacturer/tmpl/edit.php 
line 24

which I have;

form->getField('body')->save(); ?>

so I don't have save() function somewhere? when save gets call, I create save function in database call in models folder? 
I was trying to display the edit page for manufacturer.
any idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like getField('body') is not returning an object, and then you're trying to call save on this non-entity.

Comment: thanks !I will check my model and tables folder. by the way, redeclare class ManufacturerModelManufacturer meaning that I define it somewhere else too?

Comment: i actually did fix the redeclare in it. in one of the file name is lowercase. but I still can't find why getField('body') doesn't work;

Comment: This is funny but when i remove the getField('body')->save() to just  getField('body'). it returns value to me. so I don't have save(). Where do I put save() function? [I am very new to MVC in Joomla] thanks again!

Comment: I did it! thanks I actually go over it again. and at least the warning is gone now.

Comment: Good deal. If the answer helped, consider clicking the check to accept it. that marks it so other SO users know it's been answered.